# Add description to each entity reference

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, entities

I'm using Drupal 8 to build a new web app. I am allowing the user to add connections to other content on the site using taxonomy entity references. I'd like them to be able to add a description to each reference - i.e. select 'Node X', and add a description about the relation to 'Node X'.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a code solution, you can do this in a custom field type, see this answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/231162/47547.

If you want to do this in UI, you can use [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) or [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) to bundle the two fields entity reference and description.

Comment: Paragraphs is a beautiful solution for this. Thanks very much.